# Error when adding custom DynamoDBMapperConfig bean to a Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Spring boot project set up with JPA and Spring Data DynamoDB. I can get items from the DynamoDB table by Partition Key and the Sort key.

As the table name will be different depending on the envirnement, I tried to use a costum DynamoDBMapperConfig as below:

```
@Bean
public DynamoDBMapperConfig dynamoDBMapperConfig() {
    return DynamoDBMapperConfig.builder()
            .withTableNameOverride(tableNameOverrider()).build();
}

private DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride tableNameOverrider() {
    return DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride.withTableNameReplacement("mytable-dev");
}
```

Once I use that configuration ( or event when using just `DynamoDBMapperConfig.builder().build()` ) I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.hashCode()" because "key" is null
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:964) ~[na:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$StandardModelFactory.getTableFactory(StandardModelFactories.java:79) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.64.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.getTableModel(DynamoDBMapper.java:393) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.64.jar:na]
at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.core.DynamoDBTemplate.getTableModel(DynamoDBTemplate.java:223) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.AbstractDynamoDBQueryCreator.create(AbstractDynamoDBQueryCreator.java:69) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.AbstractDynamoDBQueryCreator.create(AbstractDynamoDBQueryCreator.java:42) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

**A DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride** object—Instructs the mapper instance to ignore the table name specified by a class's DynamoDBTable annotation, and instead use a different table name that you supply. This is useful when partitioning your data into multiple tables at runtime.

Are you dealing with multiple tables? Can you try removing the tableNameOverrider and see if the NPE disappears?